# DecimalFormat not working properly when input is xx.x

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have below code for `DecimalFormat`.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.text.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        double d = 50.12345;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(df.format(d));

        d = 50.0;
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.println(df.format(d));

        d = (double) (1*1.000/Integer.parseInt(2+"")/1.000*100);
        df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
        System.out.print(df.format(d));

        }
}
```

This gives me output as below.

```
50.12
50
50
```

The problem I am facing is in second number. I wanted to print it as 50.00.

Any idea how can I do the same?

### [Demo](http://ideone.com/oTVklf)

Comment: Read the doc : # - Digit, zero shows as absent / 0 - Digit. Read the section special pattern characters http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Link is not working any more :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use 0.00 as the format. # means an optional digit.

You can find all the formatting codes and their meanings here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
    double d = 50.12345;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    System.out.println(df.format(d));
    d = 50.0;
    System.out.print(df.format(d));
```